# ValidatorError: Path `lastName` is required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

I'm new at Node.js and really a newbie at MongoDB.

I'm trying to make an authentication system using Google OAuth 2.0 and passport.

I keep getting this error:
`` Error: User validation failed: lastName: Path `lastName` is required. ``

Can you help me? I got this code from GitHub and I'm trying to modify it, but this error doesn't let me continue my project.

This is the problematic code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const User = require('../models/User')

module.exports = function (passport) {
  passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
      {
        clientID: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
      },
      async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        const newUser = {
          googleId: profile.id,
          displayName: profile.displayName,
          firstName: profile.name.givenName,
          lastName: profile.name.familyName,
          image: profile.photos[0].value,
        }

        try {
          let user = await User.findOne({ googleId: profile.id })

          if (user) {
            done(null, user)
          } else {
            user = await User.create(newUser)
            done(null, user)
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err)
        }
      }
    )
  )

  passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done(null, user.id)
  })

  passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
    User.findById(id, (err, user) => done(err, user))
  })
}
```

Comment: I would recommend checking the `profile.name` properties. The mongoose error is telling you `lastName` is missing.

Comment: @jasonandmonte Oh my god, thank you! I realized that the Google account that I used for logging in hadn't a last name.